# Chart.js: I don't see xAxes texts sometimes

Tags: chart.js

I'm using Chart.js (2.9.4). I don't see hours (xAxes) only at some dayhours. For example: at 19 hour is everything ok but at 20 hour I don't see anything at xAxes. I don't know why.

Example is here: https://asteroid.vsevjednom.cz/
Is there something bad in my code?

I tried to search anything about this but without success.

Wow, reason is little fontSize. 6 = ok but bigger than 6 hides everything.

Hmm, this works:

```
fontSize: (window.innerWidth<500 ? 6 : (window.innerWidth<600 ? 7 : (window.innerWidth<700 ? 8 : (window.innerWidth<800 ? 9 : (window.innerWidth<900 ? 10 : 12)))))
```

Uaaa, I must use little font size 4px. WHY?

Comment: Consider to set `xAxes.ticks.autoSkip` to `false`